# Is there an SE site where asking about the format of a 2D barcode is on topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I have a 2D barcode that I don't recognize the format of. Is there a site on the Stack Exchange network where that question would be suitable? If so, which one?

Comment: Identification questions aren't widely popular. Some sites allow them, some have banned them from the start. I don't know any site that will take guesses on 2D barcodes.